# Case insensitive search between two strings in file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line, grep

I have a file constructed the following way:

```
# comment with keyword One
some code here
and some more code

# another comment with keyword Two
some code

# more comments and keyword Three
lots
of
code
```

I'm trying to extract the comments and corresponding code lines given a keyword, in a case-insensitive way. For example:

```
$ cat file.txt | find_by_keyword one three
# comment with keyword One
some code here
and some more code

# more comments and keyword Three
lots
of
code
```

I had previously used `awk '/^#.*('$se').*$/,/^$/'`, where `$se` is a regex I build from the provided keywords (`(one|two)`). However, I couldn't get it to be case-insensitive. It didn't seem like a good idea to permute user input with variants of cases...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, you can use case insensitive pattern matching:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "$*")
sed -En "/^#.*($pattern)/I,/^$/p"
```

The first command builds a pattern like `one|three`; the sed command uses extended regular expressions (`-E`) and suppresses output by default (`-n`); it then prints the range from any comment line matching the pattern (`I` flag for case insensitive matching) to the next blank line.

Comment: I thought, the `I` option would work only with commands like `s`. This works great

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk, just set `IGNORECASE`:

```
$ se='ONE|two'
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^#.*('$se').*$/,/^$/' file.txt 
# comment with keyword One
some code here
and some more code

# another comment with keyword Two
some code
```

Also, it is better practice to pass `$se` in as an awk variable:

```
$ awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v se="$se" '$0 ~ "^#.*("se")",/^$/' file.txt 
# comment with keyword One
some code here
and some more code

# another comment with keyword Two
some code
```

(If you are on a Mac, GNU tools can be installed with homebrew.)

Comment: pretty insightful :-)